# How to save DLIB object detection chips properly?

Tags: c++, dlib

I am having trouble saving image chips generated by DLIB's face detection model. The code below details my workflow. I have attempted saving the whole image, `d_image` below, and that works just fine. However, when I try to save each chip I get distorted output (see example below). I'm using dlib 19.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
// object to store raw image data
cv::Mat rawImage;

// initialize the detector
dlib::frontal_face_detector detector = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();

// using shape predictor object to create dull_object_detections
dlib::shape_predictor sp;
dlib::deserialize(argv[1]) >> sp;

// for writing out images 
int image_id = 1;

while (true){
    
    // retrieve image size
    sockt.getData(&image_size, 4, NULL);
    
    if (image_size > 0) {
    
        rawImage.create(1, image_size, CV_8UC1);

        // load incoming data from a stream 
        sockt.getData(rawImage.data, image_size, MSG_WAITALL);
        
        // reshape and correct orientation 
        dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image = utils::process_frame(rawImage);
        
        // find the daces!
        std::vector<dlib::rectangle> detections = detector(d_image);
        
        if (detections.size() > 0){

            // generate additional detection data so we can use 
            // dlib's extract_image_chips function
            std::vector<dlib::full_object_detection> shapes;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < detections.size(); idx++){
                dlib::full_object_detection shape = sp(d_image, detections[idx]);
                shapes.push_back(shape);
            }

            // write each chip to disk
            dlib::array<dlib::array2d<dlib::bgr_pixel>> face_chips;
            dlib::extract_image_chips(d_image, dlib::get_face_chip_details(shapes), face_chips);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < face_chips.size(); idx++){
                std::string fname = argv[2] + std::to_string(image_id) + ".jpg";
                dlib::save_jpeg(face_chips[idx], fname);
                image_id++;
            }

        }
```

Example saved chip:

[image]

**Edit**: Added comment to `utils::process_frame`. This function accepts a 1xN array and decodes as a JPEG using OpenCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with image formats you are using:

This is OpenCV's greyscale (1-channel) image

`rawImage.create(1, image_size, CV_8UC1);`

This is BGR (3-channel) image

      `dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image = utils::process_frame(rawImage);`

Dlib should throw an exception if image has incorrect number of channels, but it does not throw it in your case. This means that somewhere in `utils::process_frame(rawImage)` the image format is changed into 3-channel- check image formats first

And this construction code `rawImage.create(1, image_size, CV_8UC1);` constructs 1-row and image_size cols image.
Something is incorrect with image size and format

Please also note, that dlib does not copy image data into `dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image` and the `rawImage` should remain unchanged by other threads until processing is finished

Anyways, you can call `dlib::toMat`, get OpenCV Mat and save it with OpenCV functions

**UPDATE:**
one more thing here:

`dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image = utils::process_frame(rawImage);`

looks like utils::process_frame returns some temporary object that is destroyed after d_image is constructed. d_image does not hold returned data and it can be lost
So I suggest you to change your code like this:

```
cv::Mat uncompressed;
tils::process_frame(rawImage, uncompressed);
dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel> d_image(uncompressed);;
```

where process_frame should take reference to cv::Mat and save its output into it

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that is not the issue. The function `process_frame` decodes the 1xN array into a JPEG using OpenCV functions. I can successfully save `d_image`as a JPEG as well. I've also tried converting using `::toMat` but I still get the same output when saved.

Comment: @Andrew, looks like now I see the real problem, I have updated my answer

Comment: that did the trick! I should've queued in on that after reading `dlib::cv_image` doesn't copy data.